# Virtual environment can't be seen in terminal but visible in settings

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm 2023.1 (Community Edition)

1. I keep projects created by PyCharm on another disk.
2. When necessary, I copy a project to my working dir, open it in PyCharm, and add interpreter.

I have just:

1. Deleted .idea folder.
2. Invalidated cache.

Problem: In settings I can see that this is my correct interpreter. But in the terminal I seem to have no access to venv.

I don't even know why `which python` doesn't show anything. In my opinion it must either show the python inside venv or global. What can I try next?

[image]

[image]